# How to merge two (or multiple) rows of jsonb array into one in SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using postgres and I have multiple entries of jsonb inside an array in a single column called observation. They're input as
`'[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 0.5}]'::jsonb`.
There are multiple rows, with multiple json elements inside of each one of them. I would like to combine them into one big entry in one row, so that I will just have one observation of one column as a result.

I have tried the following

```sql
INSERT INTO data
SELECT jsonb_agg(observation) AS concatenated_json
FROM (
  SELECT observation
  FROM test
) AS subquery;
```

But the result I got was an array of arrays. I don't want to get multiple arrays, just a single one.

Comment: Try something like:  `select jsonb_agg(j) from test cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(observation) as a(j);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO data
SELECT jsonb_agg(s.elements) FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(observation) FROM test
) AS s(elements);
```

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` to expand a json array to a set of json values. For example:

```
[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 0.5}]
[{"d": 2.2}, {"e": 2.4}, {"f": 3.5}]
[{"g": 1.7}, {"h": 5.4}, {"i": 8.9}]
```

(3 rows)

will convert into 9 rows of json values:

```
{"a": 1}
{"b": 2}
{"c": 0.5}
{"d": 2.2}
{"e": 2.4}
{"f": 3.5}
{"g": 1.7}
{"h": 5.4}
{"i": 8.9}
```

then we aggregate the json values using `jsonb_agg()` into table `data` to output one row:

```
[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 0.5}, {"d": 2.2}, {"e": 2.4}, {"f": 3.5}, {"g": 1.7}, 
{"h": 5.4}, {"i": 8.9}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
select jsonb_agg((select jsonb_object_agg(k1.key, k1.value) 
     from jsonb_array_elements(t.observation) k 
     cross join jsonb_each(k.value) k1)) 
from test t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DBXQrUvL)

This query will, for each row, merge all key-value pairs in the array elements of `observations` into a single object. Then, the merged objects are aggregated into a single array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user-defined aggregate which does what you want pretty trivially:

```
create aggregate jsonb_concat_agg(jsonb) (stype=jsonb, sfunc=jsonb_concat);
```

Then use it with GROUP BY, or since you only want one row, use it without GROUP BY:

```
with t as (select '[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}]'::jsonb p union select '[{"d":4},{"e":5},{"f":6}]'::jsonb) 
select jsonb_concat_agg(p) from t;
------------------------------------------------------------
[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 3}, {"d": 4}, {"e": 5}, {"f": 6}]
```

On the one hand it is nicer than having to unnest the objects and then reassemble them, on the other hand people reading your code might be confused by what looks like it might be a built-in function, but isn't.